# How to set percent quote to one column from a table with Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, percentage

I would like to transfert a table to another range with ArrayFormula and set only one column to %.
If I change the format it will return 4500%, but I just want 45%.

[View.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxIt3.jpg)

Link to the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eKRlcJwThbFhlk1LJB23qbhsenvJ2q5fqDGZksOGhOs/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(A1:C8; {"@"\"@"\"0\%"}))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX({A1:B8\ {C1; C2:C8%}})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks ok, but what if there are data in column D ?

Comment: @MichaelGeiser then try:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(A1:D8; {"@"\"@"\"0\%"\"@"}))`